# Can the subscriber be part of a separate package than the one that it is subscribing to?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I have the basic idea of writing a subscriber. But I am not quite sure about where it is to be placed. Suppose I am subscribing to a topic in a particular package (not written by me). Is it necessary that the subscriber code (C++ or python) be placed inside the src folder of this package or can I create a separate package just for this subscriber?

Will creating a new package for subscriber make writing/editing the the CMakeLists.txt and package.xml more difficult?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/239375/can-the-subscriber-be-part-of-a-separate-package-than-the-one-that-it-is-subscribing-to?/) by [skr_robo](https://answers.ros.org/users/25555/skr_robo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 178 on 2016-07-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Publishers and subscribers do not need to be in the same package; in fact, this is one of the strengths of ROS, because it means that you can interact with someone else's code without needing to modify it.

When you're setting up your CMakeLists and your package.xml for your subscriber, you should declare a dependency on the **message package** that contains the message type definition for the topic that you want to subscribe to. For some cases, this message may be in the package with the publisher (for custom messages), but in most cases the message definition will probably be in a separate package.

For example, most laser scanners publish a `sensor_msgs/LaserScan`, and so you should depend on the `sensor_msgs` package, and your code doesn't need a dependency on the specific driver for your laser, regardless of whether you're using a Hokuyo, SICK, or other brand of laser.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-07-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [skr_robo](https://answers.ros.org/users/25555/skr_robo/) on 2016-07-13**:
Thank you for the reply. I am looking to subscribe to the topic `/camera/depth/image_rect_color` obtained from [zed-ros-wrapper](http://wiki.ros.org/zed-ros-wrapper). So, are the message package and zed-ros-wrapper package my only dependencies?

**Comment by [skr_robo](https://answers.ros.org/users/25555/skr_robo/) on 2016-07-13**:
I mean, how do I identify my other dependencies, if any?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-07-13**:
The wiki page for `zed_ros_wrapper` doesn't document the topic type, but I suspect it's a `sensor_msgs/Image`. (`Image` type from the `sensor_msgs` package). Therefore your only dependency should be the `sensor_msgs` package.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-07-13**:
You can also use `rostopic info <topic>` to determine the type of a published topic, if there isn't good documentation.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-07-13**:
Note that your node **does not** need a dependency on `zed_ros_wrapper`

**Comment by [skr_robo](https://answers.ros.org/users/25555/skr_robo/) on 2016-07-13**:
It is `sensor_msgs`. I was concerned whether I would need any other dependencies or not. Thanks a lot.